# Connection to Azure SQL DB from Azure App Service with MSI periodically fails

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

I have a python web app deployed to an Azure App Service and using its Managed Service Identity (MSI) obtains a token and connects to an Azure SQL DB.

Everything works well, and I refresh the tokens before the 8 hour expiry. However, periodically (seems to be about once every 10 days) the db becomes unreachable and the error in the logs is:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

The current fix is to restart the App Service.

My thinking for the cause is how I obtain the token using the following code:

```
msi_enpoint  = environ.get("MSI_ENDPOINT")
msi_secret  = environ.get("MSI_SECRET")
token_auth_uri = f"{msi_endpoint}?resource={resource_uri}&api-version={token_api_version}"
head_msi = {'Secret': msi_secret}
resp = requests.get(token_auth_uri, headers=head_msi)
access_token = resp.json()['access_token']
```

And the following line from [MSFT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)

> MSI_SECRET - a header used to help mitigate server-side request forgery (SSRF) attacks. **The value is rotated by the platform**.

If the value is rotated while the app is running, then the next time the app tries to obtain the token the old `MSI_SECRET` will still be the environment variable and be an invalid credential for obtaining the token, and therefore cause the subsequent failure to login to the DB.

Does this seem right? How could we overcome this issue, as scheduled restart of the app could still miss the `MSI_SECRET` rotation?

Comment: Hmm, haven't seen this issue personally :/ by the way, are you caching the tokens? The token endpoint can't take very many requests per second and in-memory caching is recommended for the duration of the token.

Comment: @juunas yea I cache the token. With current usage of the app though, worse case scenario would be about half a dozen requests to the token endpoint. I had an idea that a User Assigned Identity might circumvent the problem without completely throwing away using token access.